# Clear the entire history stack and start a new activity on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

Is it possible to start an activity on the stack, clearing the entire history before it?

**The situation**

I have an activity stack that either goes A->B->C or B->C (screen A selects the users token, but many users only have a single token).

In screen C the user *may* take an action which makes screen B invalid, so the application wants to take them to screen A, regardless of whether it is already in the stack. Screen A should then be the only item on the stack in my application.

**Notes**

There are many other similar questions, but I haven't found anything that answers this exact question. I tried calling `getParent().finish()` - this always results in a null pointer exception. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` only works if the activity is already on the stack.

Answer (score 735, accepted):

In API level 11 a new Intent Flag was added just for this: [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

Just to clarify, use this:

## Java

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

## Kotlin

```
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

Unfortunately for API lvl <= 10, I haven't yet found a clean solution to this.
The ["DontHackAndroidLikeThis" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android/3473377#3473377) is indeed pure hackery. You should not do that. :)

**Edit:**
As per @[Ben Pearson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346232/ben-pearson)'s comment, for API <=10 now one can use [IntentCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) class for the same. One can use `IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` flag to clear task. So you can support pre API level 11 as well.

Comment: Just to clarify, use this: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Comment: without the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK the app sometimes just closes itself on android 4

Comment: IntentCompat has a flag to clear task now as well, so you can support pre API level 11 - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Comment: @BenPearson's comment helped. That can be added to the answer.

Comment: this is great because I can have a "loading" screen and the user can't use the back button to return to the loading screen after the main activity is shown.

Comment: IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is ignored on devices with API level < 10. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Comment: IntentCompat's flag is only to avoid a crash, but doesn't do anything as @David says.

Comment: any one have solution for this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364638/custom-uri-navigation-from-notification-and-from-browser

Comment: I'm the only one to have a temporarily activity before to see my activity (which is not really cool) with these flags ?

Comment: But the transition animation is working the wrong way now using those flags. The new activity should move in from the right, but it moves in from the left now.

Comment: I like it! Solved my problem.

Answer (score 55):

**Case 1:Only two activity A and B:**

Here Activity flow is A->B .On clicking backbutton from B we need to close the application then while starting Activity B from A just call finish() this will prevent android from storing Activity A in to the Backstack.eg for activity A is Loding/Splash screen of application.

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(newIntent);
finish();
```

**Case 2:More than two activitiy:**

If there is a flow like A->B->C->D->B and on clicking back button in Activity B while coming from Activity D.In that case we should use.

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(D.this,B.class);
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Here Activity B will be started from the backstack rather than a new instance because of Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK clears the stack and makes it the top one.So when we press back button the whole application will be terminated.

Comment: This worked for me. I put in ALL activities those flags. In those activities back buttons work perfectly going to the previous activity, and in the main Activity with 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();

The whole app is closed, still in memory but no active, and if u restart the app goes to the splash screen :)

Comment: This should be the best answer. If anyone has a scenario the same with me:

A->B->C->D->E->(B)

From E->B should have a result:

A->B

Answer (score 54):

**With Android's Newer Version >= API 16 use `finishAffinity()`**

**approach is suitable for >= API 16.**

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
finishAffinity();
startActivity(mIntent);
```

- Its is same as starting new Activity, and clear all stack.
- OR Restart to MainActivity/FirstActivity.

Comment: This did the trick, the flags werent working on 4.x.x for me and this worked perfectly! Thanks

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer if your goal is to finish all activities below and including the current activity and start a new activity in their own task.

Answer (score 26):

I spent a few hours on this too ... and agree that FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP sounds like what you'd want: clear the entire stack, except for the activity being launched, so the Back button exits the application. Yet as Mike Repass mentioned, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP only works when the activity you're launching is already in the stack; when the activity's not there, the flag doesn't do anything.

What to do? Put the activity being launching in the stack with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, which makes that activity the start of a new task on the history stack. Then add the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag.

Now, when FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP goes to find the new activity in the stack, it'll be there and be pulled up before everything else is cleared.

Here's my logout function; the View parameter is the button to which the function's attached.

```
public void onLogoutClick(final View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Splash.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: do you mean CLEAR_TASK instead of CLEAR_TOP?

Answer (score 13):

Immediately after you start a new activity, using `startActivity`, make sure you call `finish()` so that the current activity is not stacked behind the new one.

Comment: +1 Nice solution to prevent exactly one activity in a certain situation from beeing put onto the history stack.

Comment: does not work if you have more than one activity in the stack the finish will just clear the previous activity but not the others....

Answer (score 12):

You shouldn't change the stack. Android back button should work as in a web browser.

I can think of a way to do it, but it's quite a hack.

- Make your Activities `singleTask` by adding it to the `AndroidManifest`
  Example:

  ```
  <activity android:name=".activities.A"
            android:label="@string/A_title"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>

  <activity android:name=".activities.B"
            android:label="@string/B_title"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
  ```
- Extend `Application` which will hold the logic of where to go.

Example:

```
public class DontHackAndroidLikeThis extends Application {

  private Stack<Activity> classes = new Stack<Activity>();

  public Activity getBackActivity() {
    return classes.pop();
  }

  public void addBackActivity(Activity activity) {
    classes.push(activity);
  }
}
```

From A to B:

```
DontHackAndroidLikeThis app = (DontHackAndroidLikeThis) getApplication();
app.addBackActivity(A.class); 
startActivity(this, B.class);
```

From B to C:

```
DontHackAndroidLikeThis app = (DontHackAndroidLikeThis) getApplication();
app.addBackActivity(B.class); 
startActivity(this, C.class);
```

In C:

```
If ( shouldNotGoBackToB() ) {
  DontHackAndroidLikeThis app = (DontHackAndroidLikeThis) getApplication();
  app.pop();
}
```

and handle the back button to `pop()` from the stack.

Once again, you shouldn't do this :)

Comment: In the end I decide to leave the Stack intact and just tell the user that their current screen was invalid

Comment: Very frustrating that android doesn't let us manage the activity stack this way already. I would be tempted to use this solution in my future android apps.

Comment: Just to be clear why this should not be used: it's a nice way to create memory leaks. At some point OS may decide to kill background activities, but since `Application` takes their instances the OS will not be able to free that RAM left from the destroyed activities.

Comment: @Arhimed Are there other issues? The memory leak can be patched up by keeping only weak references.

Comment: @Navin yes, leaks can avoided with weak refs, but if after GC there will not be a live Activity ref then the entire approach is useless. Once again - don't do this, this is a wrong approach for Android.

Comment: @Arhimed True enough. I was just thinking of how this can be fixed, even though I will never use it. I figure that the Activity's class can be stored and used to recreate the object if/when needed.

Comment: Best and simplest solution I think before searching in 3 topic for answer.

Answer (score 10):

### Advanced Reuseable Kotlin:

You can set the flag directly using setter method. In Kotlin `or` is the [replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45996002/974045) for the Java bitwise or `|`.

```
intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

If you plan to use this regularly, create an Intent extension function

```
fun Intent.clearStack() {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
}
```

You can then directly call this function before starting the intent

```
intent.clearStack()
```

If you need the option to add additional flags in other situations, add an optional param to the extension function.

```
fun Intent.clearStack(additionalFlags: Int = 0) {
    flags = additionalFlags or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try below code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ManageProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK| 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: if am using like this activityis updated once again call api but previously existing all statck is cleared

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Intent logout_intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
logout_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
logout_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
logout_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(logout_intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 5):

For me **none** of the above methods **not work.**

Just do this to **clear all previous activity**:

```
finishAffinity() // if you are in fragment use activity.finishAffinity()
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DestActivity.class); // with all flags you want
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainPoliticalLogin.this, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Java: -**

```
 startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChooseServiceActivity.class)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes your android emulator might fails to connect eclipse DDMS tool and ask for adb to start manually. In that case you can start or stop the adb using the command prompt.

Comment: Sometimes your android emulator might fails to connect eclipse DDMS tool and ask for adb to start manually. In that case you can start or stop the adb using the command prompt.



Intent i = new Intent(OldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
// set the new task and clear flags
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(i);

Answer (score -2):

I found too simple hack just do this add new element in  `AndroidManifest` as:-

```
<activity android:name=".activityName"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:noHistory="true"/>
```

the `android:noHistory` will clear your unwanted activity from Stack.

Comment: This aproachment can cause issues on Android 6.0+, if you ask for permitions in this Activity.