# Android - nuke the previous app history

Tags: android, notifications, history

Here's scenario. Say I have an app that I was using and navigated from activity to activity so now there's some history there. Then I switched to another app so my first one is on the background. If I return to it I would be able to click "Back" to navigate the history and traverse 1st app steps.
Now imagine that I also have a notification that when clicked will bring one of the activities of the first app. Currently when that happens and I hit "Back" I will return to the previous history stack. My requirement - if I call activity using notification then I should have no history, If I hit back, the app should simply exit. Is is doable and how?
This is related to my [other former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android) which in the retrospect didn't really got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking up the various launch modes such as [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask)

Comment: This is actually right answer, I don't know who took a point form it but they are smoking bad weed. The trick is to add flag not to `PendingIntent` but to the `Intent` it will trigger. Something like this:           

        `final Intent i = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);`