# My app won't close when i press the back button

Tags: android

I'm having a weird issue; my app won't close when i press the back button, even if i override the onBackPressed with a finish() it won't work...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    finish();
}
```

What can cause this? maybe a handler not closed or something?

Thanks

Comment: have you use Fragment or Activity ?

Comment: It's an activity that loads a fragment in a Frameview, it also call classes with network/IO methods.

Comment: Add super.onBackPressed();

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I close my application on back pressed in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799558/how-can-i-close-my-application-on-back-pressed-in-android)

Comment: @Ragaisis Read the question properly before claiming it's a duplicate.

Comment: normally you don;t have to override onBackPressed method to finish the activity...as it's the implicit/default operation of back button in android.....whereas on your problem...try using @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode,KeyEvent event)
 {if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_BACK)finish():}

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have removed super ..add super in your onBackPressed method

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed()
 {

  super.onBackPressed();  
  finish();
}
```

Comment: and if it is a fragment then call popBackStack() method

Comment: I had a piece of bad code plus forgot to call the super. So i'll mark this as the right answer. Thanks

Comment: @Motheus `super.onBackPressed()` just calls `finish()`. I don't think this is the correct answer. They do the same thing. The reason it works for you now is probably because of the bad code you said you had.