# How to clean back stack on Android API 10 (Android 2.3.3)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-compatibility

I would like to know how can I clean all previous activities of the stack (except the new one), but I want that in Android API 10 (Android 2.3.3).

Guided with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344635/1383227), I know it is not directly possible because the flag dedicated to do that exists since API 11.

But I would like to know if this is possible maybe with some compatibility or if someone has any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to always do this? Or just in certain situations. Because if you always want ativities to go away when you start a new activity you can just call `finish()` on the current activity when you call `startActivity()` for the next one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On way to do this is to always start your activities using `startActivityForResult()`. In the case where you want to clean the activity stack have the current activity call `setResult(RESULT_CANCELED)` and then call `finish()`. In all activities (except your main or "root" activity) have the following method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Want to clear the activity stack so I should just go away now
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED); // Propagate result to the previous activity
        finish();
}
```

This will finish all activities in the stack.

Comment: Thank you @David Wasser, that's the thing!

Answer (score 0):

You could add in manifest file android:noHistory="true" to each activity that you don't want to keep in the stack

Comment: This is usally a bad idea. This will prevent the user from using the "BACK" key to go back to a previous activity. Also, if the user ever navigates away from the application (to answer a phone call, for example), he won't be able to return to the app where he was. It will start all over again. Not recommended.