# how to start an Activity with all clear on history

Tags: android, android-activity

Activity moved like below.

A(login view)

code:

```
startActivity(B);
finish();
```

-> B(main view, **disable to go back to A**) 
-> C 
-> D(logout button pressed)

when I press logout Button,
`startActivity(A)` with `Flags.(like clear_top and single_top)`

I don't want to go back to Activity 'D'.
If I press back button, application should be closed. 
but, back to 'D'.

I tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` ('A' finished. so, it doesn't work)

`minSdkVersion`: 10 (cannot use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`)

Comment: have you tried adding 'single top' flag as well?

Comment: yeah I did both together, 1. clear_top, 2. single_top

Comment: Does this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android? If not, you should try explain more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Jonik Unfortunately CLEAR_TASK has API issue

Comment: What do you mean by "API issue"? Are you targeting API levels older than 11? (Mentioning your `minSdkVersion` in the question is a good idea.)

Comment: @Jonik yes, it does. added minSdkVersion.

Comment: Alright. Try this: [How to clean back stack on Android API 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234430)

Comment: should I do something now? close question or .. (then how to close?)