# Android: open activity without save into the stack

Tags: android, back-stack

I have 2 activities: Main and List.

From Main you can open List; from List you can open Main.

I'd like it so that every opening of List does **not** get saved into the 'history'. So, pressing back from Main **cannot** return to List.

Is it possible?

Comment: If 'list' starts 'main' then have it call `finish()` immediately after `startActivity(...)`. That way if the user presses BACK from 'main' there will be nothing to go back to.

Comment: this is for notification navigation but the concepts may be applicable http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse

Comment: please accept the answer that says to `finish()` current activity after starting the next one!

Answer (score 174, accepted):

When starting your list's `Activity`, set its [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) flags like so:

```
Intent i = new Intent(...); // Your list's Intent
i.setFlags(i.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); // Adds the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag
startActivity(i);
```

The [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) flag keeps the new `Activity` from being added to the history stack.

NB: As @Sam points out, you can use `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);` instead. There is no functional difference.

Comment: Just a little comment on this method:this one will work perfectly if there is only 2 Activity.
But if the list Activity is able to launch another Activity( let say third Activity), a press to the back button in the third Activity will return to the main Activity and not the list Activity

Comment: Indeed. Unfortunately, there is no way to avoid that. There is no `Intent` flag which states "only adds to history if not returning to the `Activity` of origin".

Comment: no but the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag will do the job, list Activity will be added to the history but always at the top, so a back press from main Activity will not display the list Activity

Comment: @VinceFR I don't think that's right. It starts a new task (set of `Activity`s) that operate independently of the previous `Activity`. So, if you started the main `Activity` from within this new task, it would also count as part of that new task. If `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` was instead applied to the *main* `Activity`, that may solve the issue.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you used `setFlags()` with `getFlags()` instead of [`Intent.addFlags()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addFlags%28int%29)?

Comment: @Sam Habit, probably. That's just how I'm used to doing bit flags. Good catch.

Comment: @VinceFR it's exactly what I want ! a -> b -> c and return directly to c-

Comment: Add the following empty method to your next activity to prevent exiting the app on clicking back button:

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
 }

Comment: Unfortunately the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY did not work for me. In my example I launch an intent with the above flag, then when clicking to go back the app previously launched with the intent is still in the back stack.

Comment: please see the answer that says to `finish()` current activity after starting the next one!

Answer (score 100):

In the manifest file add:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

to the activity that you don't want to keep on the stack.

Comment: is thre any difference from starting activity with flag no_history?

Comment: Like you said in your question "every opening of list DOES NOT be saved into 'history'" Therefore whenever you open your application again that will bring you to the main activity

Comment: @MarcinS. when app is not in recent app list it is not working. Can you please explain about it why this is happening

Comment: So what is the difference between those 2 approaches (manifest and flag) ?

Comment: @pumbosha Manifest approach will always leave the activity out of the history.  The flag approach lets you control that behavior at runtime.

Comment: I have a crash with no log when I add this and then ask for some permissions in that activity (Kotlin)

Answer (score 30):

Use the new task with clearing. This worked in my case when the other options didnt.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

[Clear the entire history stack and start a new activity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android)

Comment: This would be great, but is there a way to stop the system's sweeping "changing task" animation? Adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION doesn't prevent it, unfortunately!

Comment: this impacts on the application speed?

Answer (score 27):

It seems, if you call finish() on your activity right after you have opened another, the one that is finished is removed from the stack.

for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: If your phone is no so fast you'll see as previous activity is moving off.

Comment: @Nolan that is only if you finish before you start activity

Comment: this is the best answer!! c'mon accept it instead!

Answer (score 11):

In my particular case `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` did not work. Neither did `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` alone by themselves work.

However `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` together did work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FooActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Not the answer to this question, but exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

Late answer, but adds some depth to other answers. It all comes down to what do you want to happen with other activities started from that activity

**Option 1 - Just this one activity should not have history of calling activity**

Then just do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i);
```

**Option 2 - All activities started from that specific activity should not have history**

Then add in manifest of the calling activity:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

But if you do want to have history in new activity, then you have to manually remove the flag:

```
Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.removeFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i);
```

Hope that clears up other answers :)

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add a way to do this in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val i = Intent(this, LogInActivity::class.java)
startActivity(i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK))
```

Comment: More of a Kotlin way:

        ```Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        }.also {
            startActivity(it)
        }```

Answer (score 3):

Try FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP if the activity is already running:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

add the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your `Intent`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Answer (score 0):

**case : 1**

*use this flag*

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

*in this case activity transition no smoothly working blank white page before going startactvity*

**cas 2 :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

*If your phone is no so fast you'll see as previous activity is moving off , I hope to days most off the device will take care of this*

Answer (score -5):

Can you not override the back button on the particular activity to stop the 'return' functionality?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. It is acceptable to intercept BACK for specific purposes but to do it purely to consume the BACK press silently and preventing termination of an `Activity` is not good practice.

Comment: Agree entirely ^ just an option.

Comment: There is [`OnBackPressed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) for that.