# Android finishing activity not working

Tags: android, android-listview

Once the user chooses a product from my ListView, it then puts the selected text from that ListView into an EditText. The problem I am having is when the user selects a product from the list, and then presses back, it comes up with the list again instead of returning to the EditText activity.

I have tried using "finish();" after the activity starts but nothing seems to be working.

Activity that holds the EditText that launches the List activity:

```
        EditText CPU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4);
    CPU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent CPUList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    CPUList.class);
            startActivityForResult(CPUList, 1);
            Intent i = getIntent();
            String product = i.getStringExtra("key");
            EditText CPU = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4));
            CPU.setText(product);

        }
    });
```

List view class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle OnsaveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(OnsaveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cpulist);

    ListView listViewCPU = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCPU);
    listViewCPU.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    String CPUList[] = {

 "CPU's go here", "CPU's go here", "CPU's go here", "CPU's go here" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CPUList);

    listViewCPU.setAdapter(adapter);

    listViewCPU.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View myView,
        int pos, long mylng) {
    String CPU = (String) listview.getAdapter().getItem(pos);

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("key", CPU);
    setResult(1, i);

    finish();

    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are calling `finish()` on the wrong `Activity`. If you want the list `Activity` to finish then that's where you need to call `finish()`

```
  @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View myView,
            int pos, long mylng) {
        String CPU = (String) listview.getAdapter().getItem(pos);

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                ListmenuActivity.class);

        i.putExtra("key", CPU);
        startActivity(getIntent());
        startActivity(i);

        finish();  // finish here

    }
```

and remove `finish()` from your `EditText Activity`

Another issue I see is it looks like you are starting that second bit of code with the first using `startActivityForResult()` but you aren't sending back a result in your second code. Instead, you seem to be starting another `Activity`. It seems that second bit should be more like

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View myView,
            int pos, long mylng) {
        String CPU = (String) listview.getAdapter().getItem(pos);

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("key", CPU);
        setResult(1, i);

        finish();  // finish here

    }
```

Comment: I'm confused on your flow. What is `ListmenuActivity` and which do you want to close?

Comment: ListmenuActivity is the activity that holds the EditText, and I want to close CPUList once the user has chosen their product.

Comment: That's now fixed that issue I was having but now once I click a product from the ListView, it doesn't appear in the EditText for some odd reason, thanks anyway.

Comment: Please accept if it fixed your issue. The second issue is probably because all of the code you have after `finish()` in the `onClick()` should be inside `onActivityResult()`. [See the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for how to use that appropriately

Comment: Updated my code and have put "startActivityForResult(CPUList, 1);" before the code(see above). Nothing seems to be working, will you be able to assist me, I've looked at the "See the docs", I can't find the issue here, thanks.

Comment: No, I meant the code below that, getting the intent data from the list should go in the method `onActivityResult()`. That method is called after calling `setResult()` in your list `Activity`

Answer (score 2):

You need to launch your activity in a way that it doesn't get added to back stack.
Here's how you do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358563/375929