# How can I close activites that I have accessed before, and jump to the main activity?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

In my MainActivity I have buttons which allow me to open other activities, and, inside of these, I have more buttons that open more activities…

The question is this:

When I am, let's say, in the third sub-level of activities, I have added a menu_button that allows me to go back to the MainActivity. But, when I click it, the MainActivity opens, but it obviously does not close the others. How can I do that?

This is the current block of code that makes the jump:

```
case Resource.Id.home:

Intent intent = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
this.StartActivity(intent);

return true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you should do it

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
this.StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to keep any of the activities besides the Main one in backstack at all?

If not, you can open each one without adding them to backstack. See example here [Android: open activity without save into the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358485/android-open-activity-without-save-into-the-stack)

Comment: yes, for example in the third one I may want just to go back to the second one and not to the the first.

Comment: There are a couple of approaches described here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007998/on-logout-clear-activity-history-stack-preventing-back-button-from-opening-l I like the Broadcast one.