# Android back stack

Tags: android, back, android-task

I have an application with several Activities in Android A,B,C,D. I have a question about the back stack.

A->B->C->D it is a normal sequence.

My question is : when i press the back button in Activity D, i have to go to the Activity B, not back to ActivityC. Since ActivityC have some imageView i want to save, i don't want to use noHistory to destroy the ActivityC. it is possible to do that

A1->B1->C1->D1

the back stack should be: D1->B1->A1 .    C1 saved some imageView and if  C1 launch again, the imageView in C1 will contain the same images. Is it possible just modify the code in ActivityC??

thank you

Comment: Don't add C to backstack ,so that while pressing back it will directly go to B.

Comment: handle the transition in onBackPressed() of each activity and navigate Accordingly

Comment: At what point of time, you want to save the image in activity C?

Comment: @sunil sunny  But if don't add C to backstack, activityC will be destroyed and the data will be gone

Comment: @uick learner Have other method to do that?? Because i cannot modify the code in ActivtiyB and ActivityD, i just modify the code in ActivityC

Comment: @yeunhangyeung No you are not destroying C.It's still there, you didn't add it to stack that's all. What you want to do is create  a main class and  all the fragments will be navigated from here. So you have instances of all the fragments and you can use instance of C to see  the saved image.

Comment: @sunil sunny how to don't add C to backstack???  thank you for your help

Comment: @yeunhangyeung Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12358563/3111083 . It would be better if you use fragments instead of activities.

Comment: @sunil sunny  OK thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should call `finish()` in activity C after, starting of activity D

```
startActivity(intent);
finish()
```

Comment: He can't destroy activity C, since there's an image there he want to save

Comment: He can use something to load image separately from activity, or use Picasso for example, it will cache image on disk

Comment: Have method to save the image? If the image can save, finish() is ok.

Comment: If you loading image from server, and you just don't want to waste user traffic again, you can use Picasso lib, it will cache image in RAM and disk. So the next load will be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Handle onBackPressed() of each activity. So that after back pressing on D, it will redirect to B, then similarly to A.

Comment: Can i just modify the code in ActivityC? Something like hide ActivityC in backtack

Comment: Make a call to B in the the onBackPressed() of D. So it will redirect to B rather than C. and when you again call to existing C, it will come up with previous state. Just handle onBackPressed() of each activity to call existing activities from the satck

Comment: I think you should add launch modes to your answer.

Comment: This will helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity

Comment: Because i am writing a library. The activityC is a library activity. I just can modify codes in library activity.So that, i cannot make change in B and D

Answer (score 0):

Use [onActivityResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) methods of an activity:-

Here is how it will work -

Use `startActivityForResult()` method while you are starting `activity`

While when you are going back
`Activity D` - before finishing write -

```
Intent i = getIntent();
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

Your `D` is finished and `c's` `onActivityResult()` will be called - save your data and call `finish()` with above methodology, It will go to `B's` `onActivityResult()`.