# LiveData Value Reappearing When Returning to Screen After Opening New Screen

Tags: android, android-livedata

## Issue

I have implemented the YouTube intent from a Fragment when a user clicks on an item in an app's RecyclerView cell. The click event is handled in xml via Data Binding and passed to the bound **ViewModel** which passes the **LiveData** value representing the click event to the **Fragment**.

```
startActivity(YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(activity, content.id, false, false))
```

However, after triggering `onBackPressed()` to close the activity launched from YouTube and returning to the original app screen, the YouTube activity reappears when the screen is rotated as if the YouTube activity's `finish()` method has not been called.

## Expected

Rotating the screen after closing the YouTubeActivity does not trigger the YouTubeActivity to re-show unexpectedly.

## Attempted Solutions

1. Experimented with changing the context passed into the Intent from `context` to `activity`.
2. Called `context.startActivity(...)` from the Fragment as opposed to `startActivity(...)`
3. Added a flag to the new activity intent: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)`as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358485/android-open-activity-without-save-into-the-stack).
4. Wrapped YouTube intent in a "headless" Fragment (a Fragment with no UI) in order to try and control the lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

This is not related to the YouTube API, but rather the Android Architecture library component **LiveData**. I am using a **LiveData** variable to pass a click event, which is being emitted again when the screen rotates.

The best solution is outlined by Jose Alcérreca in his Medium post [LiveData with SnackBar, Navigation and other events (the SingleLiveEvent case)](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150).

In summary, Jose created an [**Event**](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JoseAlcerreca/5b661f1800e1e654f07cc54fe87441af/raw/d1d9ad561c16f4d04367424ac5f5b305ba691852/Event.kt) class that keeps track if the event has been handled.That way, when the screen is rotated the **ViewModel** and **LiveData** do not emit a value that is no longer valid for a single event.