# How can i remove first activity in the Activity Stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activities, A: LoginAcitivty, B: SignupActivity, C: HomeActivity
and the flow is A -> B -> C.
and if I signup in the SignupActivity, then I go to HomeActivity.
but there is a problem. when I click the back button on my device. I can see the LoginActivity again.
So i thought first, when i click the sign-up button, i go back to LoginActivity
and then in the LoginActivity, i go to HomeActivity by using Intent for the HomeActivity. and also i wrote finish() in the LoginActivity.
this is my code.

```
 <SignupActivity>
 val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("transfer", "transfer")
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()

 <LoginActivity>
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    if (intent.hasExtra("transfer")) {
        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

but it also doesn't work.
when i click the back button on my device in the HomeActivity, i expected that the app will end.
but i can still see the LoginActivity and i push back button again, then it's end.
plz help me.

Comment: Initially Login screen shown, of login success move to home activity. while taping the signup button it reached to signup activity and if success go to home activity?

Comment: yeah, at first, the LoginActivity is shown, and it has a button for Sign-up, so when i click the the button, i can go to the SignupActivity. and i have to fill some information. and click  complete button or something, then i can go to the HomeActivity. but the problem is, when i click back button on my device. i can still see the LoginActivity.

Comment: Please check my answer. I explained in Kotlin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: open activity without save into the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358485/android-open-activity-without-save-into-the-stack)

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of `Android` activities as your default launch mode of each of the activities is `standard`.

We can fix it in two ways. I will explain one way which is not bothering about the launch mode thing.

1. LoginActivity -> You should start the SignupActivity as

   ```
    activity.startActivityForResult(Intent(activity,SignupActivity::class.java), YOUR_REQUEST_CODE)

     override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, 
                                                     data: Intent?) {
                if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == 
   RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                   // move to Home activity and `finish()` the current 
                   //login screen
            }
        }
   ```
2. LoginActivity -> You should start the `HomeActivity` if login success and `finish()` the login screen.