# Kill all activities except for home

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have the following stack of activities on an Android application:

```
A -> B -> C
```

On C, I can go back home ("A") using startActivity with the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` intent flags. This clears the stack out of activities B and C so it's just A. Fine so far; this is my equivalent of "home".

However, I have another section - "E" - and I want it to clear the whole stack *except* for home ("A"). As in:

```
Activity stack: A -> B -> C
(User clicks on "E" button)
Activity stack result: A -> E
```

I've tried using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when opening subsection ("B", "E", etc) but there's no way to clear the previous task it seems. I've also tried `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME` but it doesn't seem to do anything (how do you even set what's "home" anyway?).

Is it possible?

Comment: If you don't need to return to a previous `Activity`, why don't you just call `finish()` in each `Activity` immediately after calling `startActivity(...)` to start the next?

Comment: Hi. A similar question with answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android . :) If you're using API < 11, then you have no choice but to create your own logic to clear the stacks. But if you're using API >= 11, you can just use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`.

Comment: Squonk: because I may have a trail of activities before deciding to go back to a different path. In my example, `finish()` would only close C, not B and C.

Comment: Arci: you're right, that seems to do the trick. However, my app supports API v8, so I guess that's why I hadn't ran into it (and why I can't use it...). Appreciate the answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not too complicated solution would be to add an extra to the 'clear top' `Intent` you're passing to `Activity` A. Based on that information you can then take action whenever `Activity` A receives a new `Intent`.

For example. you could set up a series of 'commands' that you identify when receiving an `Intent` in `Activity` A and based on which you then do something; i.e. start `Activity` E.

Alternatively, since and `Intent` is parcelable, you could attach the `Intent` that starts `Activity` E as an extra to the 'clear top' `Intent` you send to `Activity` A. Rather than identifying a command, you can then simply check if there's a 'forwarded intent' and call `startActivity(forwardedIntent)`.

In all these cases the clear top flag will result in B and C being popped, leaving A. `Activity` A will then take care of launching E. The flow should be fast enough to not result in any visual flashes, e.g. from `Activity` A briefly displaying before `Activity` E takes over.

I'm not sure if the behaviour you're after will make sense to the user, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks MH. I initially thought this would be an odd solution but it actually works well. I'm just running my "main menu" intent now and passing an additional "command" as a parameter. The main menu activity receives the new intent on `onNewIntent()` and then opens the new activity. It all happens invisibly, so no glitches.

Also: the behavior may seem odd, but it makes sense because almost all activities on my application have a sliding menu. Going from C to E means the user opted to go to a different section of the application, so going back should go back to the main menu activity, not C.