# Start fresh application every time

Tags: android, android-activity

Right now, what is happening is when I press home-key, last active activity is displayed. But what I want is to start the application as new every time the user presses home key and start the app from launcher. Please help

Comment: Similar approach to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android

Comment: Why? What does the user gain by your proposed behavior?

Comment: Security .. Consider this case - the user presses the home key and forgets to log out of the app and later, when the app is relaunched, instead of asking for user-credentials, app's data is shown directly.

Comment: Implement a configurable timeout mechanism for user credentials, rather than blindly wiping them out simply because something else took over the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override onPause() event when you pressing home button and in there you can implement finishing your activity.
with setting intent flag as FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP on starting your Activity your back stack would be clear so with finishing the last activity there is no activity on the task and stack

Answer (score 0):

While creating intent you can set the flag. for example

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```