# finish activity when back button twice pressed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am creating an application here i need to finish activity when user twice pressed back button. Here is my code what i tried

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
}
```

tried this too

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
{
    finish();
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

this helps me to finish activity once back button pressed.

Pls i need your suggestion. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok...here is a **longer, but effective way** of doing this...

**1)** Make a global vairable in your class like...

```
private boolean backPressedToExitOnce = false;
private Toast toast = null;
```

**2)** Then implement onBackPressed of activity like this...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (backPressedToExitOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        this.backPressedToExitOnce = true;
        showToast("Press again to exit");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                backPressedToExitOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

**3)** Use this trick to handle this toast efficiantly...

```
/**
 * Created to make sure that you toast doesn't show miltiple times, if user pressed back
 * button more than once. 
 * @param message Message to show on toast.
 */
private void showToast(String message) {
    if (this.toast == null) {
        // Create toast if found null, it would he the case of first call only
        this.toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    } else if (this.toast.getView() == null) {
        // Toast not showing, so create new one
        this.toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    } else {
        // Updating toast message is showing
        this.toast.setText(message);
    }

    // Showing toast finally
    this.toast.show();
}
```

**4)** And use this trick to hide toast when you activity is closed...

```
/**
 * Kill the toast if showing. Supposed to call from onPause() of activity.
 * So that toast also get removed as activity goes to background, to improve
 * better app experiance for user
 */
private void killToast() {
    if (this.toast != null) {
        this.toast.cancel();
    }
}
```

**5)** Implement you onPause() like that, to kill toast immidiatly as activity goes to background

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    killToast();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Hope this will help...:)

Comment: I've created a class, added the `Context` and `LENGTH` as its args, and made it static. Now using it globally  in my app. Thanks

Comment: @Pedram Great, that is an wonderful idea...

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean to check if the button is pressed twice

```
boolean isFinsihActivity = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isFinsihActivity) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    isFinsihActivity = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the correct way is to wait for second back

```
private boolean _doubleBackToExitPressedOnce    = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

Log.i(TAG, "onBackPressed--");
if (_doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
    super.onBackPressed();
    return;
}
this._doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to quit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        _doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    }
}, 2000);
}
```

This works for me... answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852910/leaving-android-app-with-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a global variable in your `Activity`

```
private int count;
```

Override `onBackPressed` in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (count == 1) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what I would do is use a timestamp for the first back click and if it happens again within the time limit I would finish.

```
long mtimeOfFirstClick
long TIME_LIMIT = 0.5 DateUtils.SECONDS_IN_MILLIS;

public void onBackPressed() {
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - mtimeOfFirstClick <= TIME_LIMIT) {
        finish();
    } else {
        mtimeOfFirstClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a mistake:
It must be "System.currentTimeMillis()" and not "System.currentTimeInMilliseconds()".

Answer (score 0):

try like this initialize the static int variable with 0 and increment the variable inside the onBackPressed() and check it value be 2;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static int i=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
    i++;
    if(i==2){

        finish();

    }

}
```

Comment: I think this is not good to wait for second back press

Answer (score 0):

do it something like this:

```
int counter=0;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            counter+=1;
            if(counter==2){
            this.finish();}
    }
```

Comment: But the second back press should happen in two seconds