# How to clear All Activity from Stack in android

Tags: android

I am try to finish activity.I have 5 activity in a Second activity i have list view and on clicking on item of list view 3rd activity is open without finishing activity. and the i come back and i click on button on 2nd  activity and go to 5 activity an there is one button lo-gout. i click on that button and go to 1 activity. so o want to finish 1st activity. how can i do. please give me solution for this i try may things.

Comment: Not so clear...but if you want to clear other activity so call with flag Activity clear top....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear the entire history stack and start a new activity on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

In your AndroidManifest.xml in your Activity tags add the following :

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

simple:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

I'm using it on my app on the same use case, the `Log out` and the `Delete account` buttons are buried after 3 activities in the stack.