# Reopen App and not show the previous activity

Tags: java, android, activity-finish

I am facing a problem right now. When I exit the app, and reopen again, it is showing me the previous activity. Is there any way I can launch MainActivity after re-opening the app again? I tried using but to no avail:

```
SecondActivity.this.finish();
Intent intent = new Intent (SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Please help me thank you.

Comment: with which activity you are facing this issue. explain with flow to help you better. Also `noHistory` is with which activity.

Comment: I'm doing a time extending app. so basically user will have to fill up the fields in the extending activity (SecondActivity) , after filling up, it will redirect user to Mainactivity. I exited the app by having a dialog box with  MainActivity.this.finish(); System.exit(0); . However when i reopen the app (i didnt kill the app) it shows the extend page (SecondActivity). By right, when i reopen, it should show me my MainActivity instead of SecondActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

See here [Clear the entire history stack and start a new activity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android)

If you want to call `finish()`, you should do it after a `startActivity` call, if you do it in any of the lifecycle callbacks, it could be called in diferent moments, and not only when navigating to other activity.

The good thing of `noHistory`, is that **the system takes care of finising the activity in the correct moment** (as you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), the system will actually call the  finish() method for you) so you can be sure that you are not calling it in a bad moment, and everything is safe (probably this doesn't seem important now, but it could be, for instance when working with threads)

Also try to read about `Empty process`

> A process that doesn't hold any active application components. The
>   only reason to keep this kind of process alive is for caching
>   purposes, to improve startup time the next time a component needs to
>   run in it. The system often kills these processes in order to balance
>   overall system resources between process caches and the underlying
>   kernel caches.
>
> An empty process is one that doesn't hold any active application
>   components. The only reason to keep such a process around is as a
>   cache to improve startup time the next time a component of its
>   application needs to run. As such, the system will often kill these
>   processes in order to balance overall system resources between these
>   empty cached processes and the underlying kernel caches.

Read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html