# Closing the background activity which has the same name

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to develop an app which has two editText fields for entering location. So I made two java files

1.`MapsActivity.java`(with `activity_maps.xml`)
2.`AutoComplete.java`(with `autocomplete.xml`)

In `MapsActivity` while clicking the 'from' text field, it will open the `AutoComplete` activity and after clicking any of the suggestions in it will open a fresh `MapsActivity` and places the clicked item . Likewise for 'to' text field also.

I am using Intents to pass the clicked values. So at last, five activities are opened when the two text boxes are filled. When I click back button ,it is showing the auto complete activity used the previous time.

**Question:**

1. Is any other way to close a particular activity with same name running behind?
2. Is there any other way to pass values by `super.backpressed()`; ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlmQa.jpg)

Comment: Why are you starting new activity when EditText is clicked?

Comment: @Jas actually I want to show the user ,a set of suggestions about the places they are searching for..!  From the same activity, it will be difficult I think..

Comment: You can easily do this using a custom alert dialog with your suggestions shown as list

Comment: Thank you Jas.. But whether it will update the suggestions for every letter being changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to clear backstack/clear_top/single_top using the intent.
Just add/set flags in intent.
or
finish activity after startActivity.
or 
you can override the onBackPressed method to call the specific activity.

Comment: But there is two activity only, if I did something to be done at the fourth time means ..it is doing it in the very first time..since it has the same name..

Comment: how actually your activities are moving

Comment: if you are moving back and fourth into these activities you can use onActivityResult method

Comment: Thank you..ankush.. But I'm very new to this.. Can you give some links or examples about this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android

Comment: first you read these how these are working actually and try to understand the flow of these methods

Answer (score 2):

You can try using startActivityForResult() method. That way you can use the result from the second activity in the first and also you wouldn't need to start a new activity. You can read up on it here [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))