# Finish previous activites without starting new activity, android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 5 activities in my application. On each activity there is a button to take it to the next activity. 
So the stack of the activity is like :

Activity 1->Activity 2->Activity 3->Activity 4->Activity 5

On the 5th Activity there is a button with which I just want to clear the previous activities. I am not starting any new activity here.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

It cannot be done with this, because a new activity has be started.

What can be done for this?

Comment: means you don't wanna start any new activity in activity 5 right ? you just wanna clear stack which us activity 1,2,3,4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @jiteshmohite yes exactly that

Comment: Call finishAffinity() on click of button.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid it also finishes the current activity which I don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to solve the problems.

**The schema:**
Each activity which is needed to be close needs to `wait for a close event`. When button close is clicked, the close event will be sent and every activity waiting for the close event will be closed.

**How to achieve:**

1. Make a class for an event for closing activity, **CloseEvent**. CloseEvent is a simple class:

   ```
   public static class CloseEvent{}
   ```
2. Register each activity for receiving Event from EventBus.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
   }
   ```
3. Subscribe each activity to receive CloseEvent.

   ```
   @Subscribe 
   public void onMessageEvent(CourierOrderTimeEvent event) {
     this.finish() // Close the activity.
   }
   ```
4. Sent the CloseEvent when the button is clicked.

   ```
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
       EventBus.getDefault().post(new CloseEvent());
     }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using startActivity() you can use startActivityForResult()

suppose from activity1 to activity5 you are lauching activity using startActivityForResult()

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);



 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, requestCode + "");
        finish();
    }
```

in Activity2 you can use

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Activity2.this, MainActivity3.class), 2);

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, requestCode + "");
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        setResult(1,intent);
        finish();//finishing activity
    }
```

like that till activity 4

in Activity 5 when you click button as mention above you can use below code.

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
setResult(5,intent);
```

please let me know if are able to solve your problem