# Clear activity from stack from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I have starting screen,which is my first activity in my application.

This activivty contains only one button and when its clicked, it should navigate to another activity which should prompt user for name.

If user press back button before confirming name, it should navigate back to the previous activity.

But when user confirm name, main activity should pop up and foregone activities should be removed from application.

I was looking for a solution and find it in creating static activity object , but i saw it was not wise and it is bad for memory.

What is the best approach for doing what i explained?

Comment: Why don't you clean the Activity stack and start a new MainActivity like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello this might be helpful check it once...

## implement this in your "UserNameActivity"

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (name.isconfirmed())
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

implement this code at which activity to clear other stack activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, newActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

I hope this is helpful for you

Comment: When implemented that, after confirming name, i get white scsreen for a 1 second before mainActivity loads..

Comment: please do this run in background process,
which purpose to use clear stack activity- It depends on how it is done

Answer (score 0):

First `Activity` should call second `Activity` using `startActivityForResult()`. In first `Activity` implement `onActivityResult()` as follows:

- If the `resultCode` is `RESULT_CANCELED` then the user has clicked the BACK key, so you don't need to do anything
- If the `resultCode` is `RESULT_OK` then the user entered his username and you can start the main `Activity` and call `finish()`. This will remove the first `Activity` from the stack.

The second `Activity` should call `setResult(RESULT_OK)` and then `finish()` when the user has confirmed their username. This will end the second `Activity` and return to the first `Activity` by calling `onActivityResult()`.

NOTE:
The second `Activity` can return data (like the entered username or whatever) to the first `Activity` as "extras" in an `Intent` that it passes to `setResult()`.