# Android: Killing an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button

I have an activity where a user put his nickname. I want to not be able to go back after this. I have tried everything but no luck. Tried so far :

**Manifest**

```
 <activity
     android:name=".NewUserActivity"
     android:noHistory="true" />
 <activity android:name=".PvP.PVPWinningActivity" />
```

**In Activity:**

```
btnEnterDungeons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {           
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editUsername.getText().toString().trim())) {
             uploadUserData();
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setClass(NewUserActivity.this, GameChooseActivity.class);
             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
             startActivity(intent);
             finish();
 }
```

or in Activity again:

```
btnEnterDungeons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editUsername.getText().toString().trim())) {
             uploadUserData();
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
             intent.setClass(NewUserActivity.this, GameChooseActivity.class);                    
             startActivity(intent);
             finish();
 }
```

None of these works. Actually, I want to completely kill the activity, no back button or any way to have access again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android/3473377

Comment: So mean when you press the back button from GameChooseActivity it comes back to NewUserActivity? or you want to start from the GameChooseActivity when the app is opened again? Please clarify

Comment: Even from GameChoose activity or another activity, pressing back, back i end to the New user,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NewUserActivity, override OnBackPressed() method
then call finish;  to kill the current activity;
See sample implementation below:

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

```
                    killActivity();

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}

private void killActivity() {
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(NewUserActivity.this, GameChooseActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    NewUserActivity.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

## One-Time Setup?

Based on my understanding you want a one-time setup Activity. Your code is fine the only problem I see is that when you open the application again it starts from the beginning. It is because there is no logic in your code to check if you have already done a one-time setup. For this, you can use `SharedPreference`.
You can create a Splash Activity and check if the one-time setup is done or not based on a boolean flag.

> So what I am suggesting is this first time the user opens the app
>   SplashActivity-->NewUserActivity--->GameChooseActivity
>   otherwise
>   SplashActivity-->GameChooseActivity

```
SplashActivity extends AppcompatActivity{

   boolean hasDoneSetUp = false;
   private SharedPreferences pref;
   private Editor editor;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle sis)
   {
      super.onCreate(sis);
      setContentView(R.layout.splash);

      pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
      editor = pref.edit();

      hasDoneSetUp = checkForSetUp();

      if(!hasDoneSetUp)
         startOneTimeSetUp();
      else
         startGameChooseActivity();

    }
}
```

#### How to do the onetime setup?

Set `hasDoneSetUp` true when the one-time setup is done and save this value in the `SharedPreference` so that when you open the application again it will check whether the one-time setup has done or not.

**Save your other data in SharedPreference or SQLiteDatabase and retrieve those data in the GameChooseActivity.**

```
public void startOneTimeSetUp(){

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editUsername.getText().toString().trim())) {
                uploadUserData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, GameChooseActivity.class);

                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
                Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("hasDoneSetup", true);           
                editor.commit(); 

                finish();
            }
}


public boolean checkForSetUp(){

     return pref.getBoolean("hasDoneSetup", true);
}

public void startGameChooseActivity(){
     Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, GameChooseActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

### Relevant links

If you don't know [What is SharedPreference?](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)
If you don't know how to use SharedPreference [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Answer (score 0):

With Android's Newer Version >= API 16 use finishAffinity()

finishAffinity(); did the trick.

As i read everywhere suggested to use just finish(); For newer API (I use >= 17 ) had to use finishAffinity();